# MySQL's AUTO_INCREMENT behavior in a multiple row insert

Tags: mysql, auto-increment, multiple-insert

I think the answer to my question is obvious but since I could not find any documentation to support it, I thought it's worth asking. At least for the record.

As we all know `AUTO_INCREMENT` fields are incremented each time an `INSERT` statement is executed. And its value can be retrieved by `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function. It is also mentioned in [MySQL's Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) that with multiple-row inserts, `LAST_INSERT_ID()` will return the first ID of the  inserted rows. Which I think is a good idea (really useful).

So here goes my question:

Can I assume in an `INSERT IGNORE INTO` statement with multiple-rows, the inserted IDs of an `AUTO_INCREMENT` field will always be sequential? Keep in mind that due to `IGNORE` modifier and the multi-user nature of MySQL server, different scenarios might happen.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No you can not assume that. One scenario where ID's would not be sequential is in replicated multi-master setup. If for example two servers exist in such setup, one will only generate even auto IDs, and the other only odd IDs (keep in mind it's just an example).

However if your setup is not something like that, then yes. At least in InnoDB inserts are atomic and are queued when targetting same table, so ID's from two different INSERT's will not interlace. (it's not documented though, so relying on it is... a bit risky)

---

How I tested IGNORE INSERT ID generation:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE  `ignoreinsert` (
    ->   `ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->   `uq` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
    ->   UNIQUE KEY `uq` (`uq`)
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.19 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO ignoreinsert VALUES (null,1),(null,2);
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.10 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM ignoreinsert;
+----+----+
| ID | uq |
+----+----+
|  1 |  1 |
|  2 |  2 |
+----+----+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT IGNORE INTO ignoreinsert VALUES (null,3),(null,1),(null,4),(null,2),(null,5);
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.08 sec)
Records: 5  Duplicates: 2  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM ignoreinsert;
+----+----+
| ID | uq |
+----+----+
|  1 |  1 |
|  2 |  2 |
|  3 |  3 |
|  4 |  4 |
|  5 |  5 |
+----+----+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: How about `IGNORE` modifier, do the duplicate rows advance the counter even though they are inserted? I ask this because I've seen that in single row `INSERT` statements without `IGNORE` modifier, the counter is incremented when some error happens, even though the row is not inserted!

Comment: Mehran Ziadloo: I just did a check to be sure, and the IDs were sequential.

Comment: My bad, using `IGNORE` modifier will not increment the counter. That is for rows which _duplicate key_ errors are turned into warnings.